# How can I extract the lines from a fill pattern in Revit using revit-api?

Tags: revit-api, revit-2015

Can I get the lines from a fill pattern in Revit? I've tried a lot of ideas, so is there anyone who has a solution?

I tried the solution from https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/dimension-on-hatch-pattern-slab/td-p/7063302, but I didn't get any results. I can only retrieve references and cannot convert them to lines when I use the "GetElement" method on a floor.